# Ruby compass issue failed since update to MACOS Catalina

Tags: ruby, gulp, macos-catalina

I have an old setup for a website using Gulp to compile the SASS files with gulp-sass. Everything has been working without any issues until I updated my Mac to Catalina.

Now when I run the gulp command to compile the SASS I get the following error:-

```
/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.3.0/lib/ruby/2.3.0/fileutils.rb: Read-only file system @ dir_s_mkdir - /c
Run with --trace to see the full backtrace
events.js:174
throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
^
Error: Compass failed
```

I have searched many forums and tried solutions such as updating Ruby, installing Gems locally etc and nothing has solved the issue.

Any direction would be great.

`"devDependencies": {
    "@babel/cli": "7.4.4",
    "@babel/core": "7.4.5",
    "@babel/plugin-syntax-dynamic-import": "^7.2.0",
    "@babel/polyfill": "^7.4.4",
    "@babel/preset-env": "7.4.5",
    "@babel/register": "7.4.4",
    "autoprefixer": "^6.3.6",
    "babel-jest": "^24.8.0",
    "babel-loader": "^8.0.6",
    "babel-minify-webpack-plugin": "^0.3.1",
    "bower": "^1.7.9",
    "bricks.js": "^1.0.1",
    "browser-sync": "^2.26.5",
    "compression-webpack-plugin": "^3.0.1",
    "concurrently": "^4.1.0",
    "cssnano": "^3.4.0",
    "eslint-loader": "2.1.2",
    "eslint-plugin-flowtype": "^2.50.1",
    "eslint-plugin-jest": "^23.2.0",
    "gulp": "^3.9.1",
    "gulp-babel": "^8.0.0",
    "gulp-compass": "^2.1.0",
    "gulp-concat-util": "^0.5.4",
    "gulp-data": "^1.2.1",
    "gulp-eslint": "^5.0.0",
    "gulp-imagemin": "^4.1.0",
    "gulp-plumber": "^1.2.1",
    "gulp-postcss": "^6.0.1",
    "gulp-print": "^5.0.0",
    "gulp-rename": "^1.2.2",
    "gulp-sass": "^3.2.1",
    "gulp-sass-lint": "^1.4.0",
    "gulp-sourcemaps": "^1.6.0",
    "gulp-twig": "^0.5.0",
    "gulp-uglify": "^1.5.1",
    "gulp-util": "^3.0.7",
    "jest": "^24.5.0",
    "jest-puppeteer": "4.2.0",
    "lodash": "^4.17.15",
    "node-sass": "^4.13.0",
    "path": "^0.12.7",
    "postcss-assets": "^4.0.1",
    "postcss-cssnext": "^2.4.0",
    "puppeteer": "^1.18.0",
    "stylelint": "^9.5.0",
    "stylelint-order": "^1.0.0",
    "uglifyjs-webpack-plugin": "^2.1.3",
    "webpack": "^4.32.2",
    "webpack-bundle-analyzer": "^3.3.2",
    "webpack-cli": "^3.3.2",
    "webpack-concat-plugin": "^3.0.0"
  },
"dependencies": {
    "babel-preset-jest": "^24.6.0",
    "chart.js": "^2.8.0",
    "jquery": "3.4.1",
    "natives": "^1.1.6"
  },`

Comment: can you provide dependencies and devDependencies values from `package.json`?

Answer (score 2):

Thank you to everyone. My issue is the SASS is written in Ruby SASS. node-sass is a wrapper for Lib SASS. Which will not work for this code base.

I am closing the question as I believe I have found the answer.

MacOS Catalina made two big changes with Ruby.

1 -The system Ruby version was upgraded from 2.3 to 2.6, and
2 - The system Ruby gems directory is no longer writable — it is not a place for installing user gems.

This is causing the issues I believe. The suggestion is to re-install Ruby with Homebrew. I have located some information on how to do this here https://gorails.com/setup/osx/10.15-catalina

Answer (score 0):

Try without Ruby and explicitly specify **node-sass**.

**gulpfile.js**

```
var gulp = require('gulp');
var sass = require('gulp-sass');

sass.compiler = require('node-sass');

gulp.task('test-gulp-sass', done => {
  sass();
  done();
})
```

```
$ npm install --save-dev gulp gulp-sass node-sass
$ npx gulp test-gulp-sass
```

Comment: Thank you for looking at this. I don't think this will work as the project is using compass and compass requires ruby. Please correct me if I have missunderstood.

Comment: Compass uses Sass, so projects can use other Sass implementations interchangeably with little refactoring. You'll see huge build performance gains too! [have a look](https://www.google.com/search?q=migrate+from+compass+to+node-sass)